# Windows File Server, Alert for Large Amount of Data Creation by Any One User over Time

Tags: windows-server-2003

With a Windows Server 2003, can I get an alert if any one user creates a certain amount of data over a certain period of time?

A quota policy seems like the implied long term solution, but this would be helpful to me in the short term.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full script to give you but you may want to look at diskuse.exe in the Server 2003 Resource Kit.  It should let you see who your top offenders are in total use, but it would take some work to store that and show your day to day changes.

[Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en)